# How do I figure out which samba users aren't configured with smbpasswd?

Tags: linux, debian, samba

I am starting a sys admin job, and this samba server is just a nightmare. People aren't able to log in, and they don't know why. After asking some questions, I think the problem is that they aren't configured with smbpasswd. How can I list out all the users that are/aren't configured with smbpasswd?

Comment: First question: is your Samba server joined to some organisational domain (Active Directory or OpenLDAP, for example) or is it completely standalone? This determines how authentication is managed, and therefore how to approach answering your question. If you don't know the answer to this, please provide the content of the `[global]` section of `smb.conf` into your question. If you need to obfuscate (mask) details, please make it crystal clear what you have changed

Comment: @roaima it is stand alone for easy access to company files over LAN.

Comment: Mine are all AD joined _for easy access to company files over LAN_. Are you **sure** it's standalone?

Comment: @roaima yes, I’m sure

Answer (score 0):

You can list the contents of the local server's Samba password file with this command

```
pdbedit -L | awk -F: 'NF>=3'
```

(Strictly speaking, you don't need the `awk` part but it helps get rid of compatibility warnings about entries in your `smb.conf` that may be printed.)

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out.